# Continuous file load directly from FTP to Snowflake using Snowpipe

Tags: ftp, copy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'd like to copy files incrementally from an FTP server into Snowflake.

Currently, I am using ADF pipeline which runs every 15 minutes and copies them into Azure Blob Storage. Then I have Snowpipes which ingest them into the target tables in Snowflake. However, I am looking for a more optimized solution.

Is there a way to load data directly from FTP to Snowflake instead of using ADF to copy files to Azure blob storage and read them from there?

Thanks

Comment: This does not look like a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to me.

Comment: Can you install anything on the FTP server? If yes, you can use SnowSQL in a cron job to upload the files into a Snowflake stage and run COPY INTO from there.

Comment: @Sergiu - No we can't install anything on the FTP server.

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 alternative options:

1. Use logic apps instead of ADF. In Logic Apps, add FTP component with (when the file is added or modified).
2. Use stream and task instead of snowpipe with ADF or Logic Apps.